# DatagridPro, Tree view I want to show data with three levels on row expansion in Material UI

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, frontend, mui-x, rowexpansion

I am using the Material UI, DataGridPro and I want to display my data like this[image]

can anyone have any idea or any example that how can I add UI like this with material UI DataGridPro?

I have tried every possible solutions and also researches on it but didn't find any useful resources.